# How to train a model to recognise a sound?

Tags: java, machine-learning, signal-processing

Im really new to machine Learning.I have a project to identify a given sound from a clip like how many times it occurs like wise.(Ex: Dog Bark)In the audio clip there will be several sound. What i need to do is recognise that particular sound from it. I red some articles about machine learning. But i still have lack of knowledge where to start this project and also I'm running out of time. I tried to plot the audio clip using Matlab waveread function. But i don't know how to train such a model and analyse the clip frame by frame to identify the particular sound.

Any help will be really appreciated. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Can i directly perform template matching for a sound?

Comment: did you try your self? or google??

Comment: i tried and google for last 2 days but i still couldn't get a single idea how to do this.

Comment: [Here are some google results](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sound+matching+algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Try feeding your machine learning model a sequence or stream of MFCC vectors obtained from overlapping windows from your audio data.  That's a basic start to one of the more common method of audio fingerprinting.

Comment: but how to create a machine learning model using Matlab for sound matching?